# How to push nested object interface array in React Typescript using useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, array-push, react-typescript

**Interface**

```
  interface ListInterface {
    listName: string;
    list: string[];
  }
```

**useState**

```
  const [initialList, setinitialList] = useState<ListInterface>({listName: "List1", list:['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six']});
  const [selectedList, setSelectedList] = useState<ListInterface>(initialList);
```

I know how to add new elements (push) to array. But having trouble when the array is in object/inteface. How do you do it with useState hooks?

```
setTheArray(oldArray => [...oldArray, newElement]);
```

I have created a simple sandbox example.

- Use the input field to add a new text to array `selectedList.list`

https://codesandbox.io/s/reacr-ts-nested-object-array-example-z1uyd?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined an object interface, so that means that you need to push an object that conforms to that type each time you want to update it.

```
  
  // ...

  const [text, setText] = useState<string>(''); // <--- set type and set to blank to remove type errors due to `text` being possibly undefined

  // ...

  const handleSubmit = (event: any) => {    
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Submitted: " + text);

    //setSelectedList({list: oldArray => [...oldArray, newElement]});
    // the above wont work because it is an array, but `ListInterface` is an object (you might want to change the name to `ListEntry` or `ListObject` to avoid confusion)

    setSelectedList({
      listName: selectedList.listName,
      list: [...selectedList.list, text]
    })

  };
```

---

Appreciate the accept. Check out @axtck's answer as well, as they make a few other important improvements to your code!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't initialize a state variable for your initial object, you could just use the interface and declare it that way:

```js
const initialList: ListInterface = {
  listName: "List1",
  list: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"]
};
```

Since you only want to update the list inside the object, you can use `functional setState()` like this:

```js
const handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
  console.log("Submitted: " + text);
  event.preventDefault();

  setSelectedList((prevState) => {
    return { ...prevState, list: prevState.list = [...prevState.list, text] };
  });
};
```

When `mapping`, make sure you pas a valid `key`:

```js
{selectedList.list.map((item, i) => {
  return <h3 key={i}>{item}</h3>;
})}
```

Full code & updated [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reacr-ts-nested-object-array-example-forked-5lsbq):

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  interface ListInterface {
    listName: string;
    list: string[];
  }

  const initialList: ListInterface = {
    listName: "List1",
    list: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"]
  };

  const [selectedList, setSelectedList] = useState<ListInterface>(initialList);
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
    console.log("Submitted: " + text);
    event.preventDefault();

    setSelectedList((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, list: prevState.list = [...prevState.list, text] };
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {selectedList.list.map((item, i) => {
        return <h3 key={i}>{item}</h3>;
      })}

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Add To List:
          <input type="text" value={text} onChange={handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: TIL `functional setState()`, that's a handy trick!

Comment: Yes, this comes out handy in a lot of situations! I only recently found out about it but used it in many ways :p so np